# Why does stack overflow occur if we do not declare our buffer as a global variable in C?

Tags: c, stack-overflow, turbo-c

Just read somewhere that,

> when large buffers are used they must be made global variables otherwise stack overflow occurs.

But i am unable to get why it would happen?

(This is for C language compilers Turbo C on windows).

Comment: thnx for the edit niko

Comment: Where did you read that?  If you need a buffer that is larger than the default maximum stack size, then you could increase the stack size in the linker or dynamically-alocate the buffer at runtime.  There is no need to resort to globals and/or statics - an approach that results in non-reentrant, thread-unsafe code/data.

Comment: hey martin, i read it in the book let us c by yashwant kanetkar pg. 453.

Comment: You need a better book:)

Comment: dude it is the best book for beginners, still you can advise me the book you think to be better as i am definitely looking to increase my skills

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, the executable file header, and OS loader, place a lower limit on the maximum stack size than they do on the global/static data.

Your linker is responsible for assembling the executable header and may be instructed to set a greater, (or smaller), maximum stack size for the executable image, so you could instruct the linker to raise that limit to accommodate your big buffer.

If you need a large buffer and don't want to increase the maximum stack, you could dynamically-allocate the buffer space at runtime.

The last option you should consider is using statics/globals.  Such code/data is not reeentrant and so not thread-safe:(

Answer (score 3):

Global variables are not allocated on the stack - they are in the read-write section of the executable, and thus won't cause stack overflows.

Comment: Dang, you beat me to it again :(

Comment: The bss stack section is read/write too, else it would not work.